# Wordpress permalink with no error 404 page

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

i am using wordpress permalink like url.com/article-name but i dont want errors 404 handled by my page - so redirected to the normal server error page. 
I am using the following .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can someone help me how i have to adjust the .htaccess code that a error is not redirected to the index.php. If i deleted the .htaccess any links redirects to the server error 404 page.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just add this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
# where 404.php is your error page
```

Comment: You got me wrong. I don't want to use that file. I want the server error 404 page

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/24616) at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ you should use

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml(\.gz)?)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(css|js|html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've edited the answer (removed a white space). Can you test again, please?

Comment: main page working again but i get erros if i click on links on the page. probably something with the wrong adding of the permalinks